# $_SESSION var behaves strangely

Tags: php, session-variables

Lately I've encountered problems using the admin area of my website. It seemed there were session problems. To see what's going on with `$_SESSION`, I've created the following script:

```
<?
session_start();
mysql_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME");

if (isset($_SESSION)) {
    echo '<pre>session var:<br/>';
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $perm = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `perm_groups` WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['perm']."'"));
    echo '<br/><br/>permission var:<br/>';
    var_dump($perm);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    echo 'no session set';
}
?>
```

$_SESSION['perm'] should contain a numeric string refering to the ID of the permission-group i have ("1" -> "admin")
After login I call the script manually and get this result:

```
session var:
array(4) {
  ["user"]=>
  &string(17) "sebastian.philipp"
  ["auth"]=>
  &bool(true)
  ["perm"]=>
  &string(1) "1"
  ["llog"]=>
  &string(19) "2013-08-21 09:48:38"
}


permission var:
array(7) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "admin"
  ["create_pages"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["delete_pages"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["edit_pages"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["manage_users"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["manage_img"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

When refreshing the page by pressing F5, it returns this result:

```
session var:
array(4) {
  ["user"]=>
  &string(17) "sebastian.philipp"
  ["auth"]=>
  &bool(true)
  ["perm"]=>
  &array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "admin"
    ["create_pages"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["delete_pages"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["edit_pages"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["manage_users"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["manage_img"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["llog"]=>
  &string(19) "2013-08-21 09:48:38"
}


permission var:
bool(false)
```

And when refreshing again, it's like this:

```
session var:
array(4) {
  ["user"]=>
  &string(17) "sebastian.philipp"
  ["auth"]=>
  &bool(true)
  ["perm"]=>
  &bool(false)
  ["llog"]=>
  &string(19) "2013-08-21 09:48:38"
}


permission var:
bool(false)
```

So it semms like `$perm` gets written to `$_SESSION['perm']`, which shouldn't happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The usual don't use mysql_* functions, seriously use mysqli_* database functions. Secondly, don't call `$perm = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(..))` in the same line. Save the result of the mysql_query to it's own variable, then use while loop to fetch the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` - Also, only need to run the Login once, add a trigger on the form, as using `isset( $_SESSION )` is quite inadequate.

Comment: I didn't encounter problems with this before. And  yes, you're right: session_start() creates the session var so it's not useful to check this. I should use isset($_SESSION['auth']) instead, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your PHP version?
It sounds like [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is activated and it shouldn't be.

Comment: It's version 5.2.17 and `register_globals` is really set to `ON`. I don't have access to the `php.ini` but I can send a request to the hoster if it's necessary. But a few days ago I didn't encounter these problems.